SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call here. Maybe you meant '==' when using os.environ in Python
I am creating a AI agent in my Jupyter Notebook on Anaconda. When I enter the following settings I get an error.
import os
os.environ("OPENAI_API_KEY")=openai_api_key
os.environ("OPENAI_MODEL_NAME")="gpt-3.5-turbo"

 Cell In[47], line 1
    os.environ("OPENAI_API_KEY")=openai_api_key
    ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call here. Maybe you meant '==' instead of '='?

This seems to be a standard statement that works on lightning.ai or even VScode editor but why doesnt it work on my Jupyter notebook running on Localhost? I am running this on my Macbook.
Next I was planning to create a few agents to create a bot to read and respond to a blog.

Use Square brackets instead of parentheses.
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]=openai_api_key
os.environ["OPENAI_MODEL_NAME"]="gpt-3.5-turbo"

It'll solve the issue.

use Square brackets
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] instead of os.environ("OPENAI_API_KEY")

